# How to load a QML component on click

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, loader

I will try to explain my problem with a simple example.

I have a `Rectangle A` and a `Rectangle B`. I want that when you click on `A`, a `view` (for example a `listView`) is loaded in `B`. If you click again on  `A`, the `listView` will disapear. 
I know it is something about `class Loader` but I have trouble to make it work correctly.

```
Rectangle {
    id: A
    MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked {
            //Load or Close listView
         }
    }
 }
 Rectangle {
     id:B
     //here load or unload the listView
 }
```

Does anyone could provide a simple example ?

NB : I don't want to use `visible` because I need to refresh `data` when the rectangle is clicked.

Comment: Use a `Loader` element

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly my question, how to use it here.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? This is really basic stuff you shouldn't have any problem with. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html

Comment: I edited my post because it was not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: A
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked {
            ld.active = !ld.active
        }
   }
}

Rectangle {
    id:B

    Loader {
        id: ld

        sourceComponent: comp
        active: false
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
         id: comp

         Rectangle { //replace this with your listview
              color: blue
         }
    }
}
```

When you click on rectangle `A` the state of loader changes and component `comp` loading/unloading.